# CPU load slowly creeping up while running coroutineScope launch periodically on Android with RoomDB update

Tags: android, performance, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

In my Android application I have a simple case where I periodically poll for a new value and then run a RoomDB Query which updates the value in the database.

```
fun updateStatus(
    sensorId: String,
    state: String,
) {
    scope.launch {
        db.statusDao().setLastState(sensorId, state)
    }
}
```

... and ...

```
infoTimer = Timer()
    infoTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(
        object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                ... in the end updateStatus() is called
            }
        },
        0,
        300,
    )
```

I noticed that while this is happening the CPU is constantly rising. Shorter the timeout the steeper it goes.

[image]

Any ideas what is causing this and how to stop it from happening?